# curl post for uploading files to croppola failing

Tags: curl, upload

I am trying to crop all the files in a folder with the croppola.com curl method the have on their site. I see the files being added, but it seems the upload/download is not completing before the script moves on. I have tried adding sleep but it doesn't seem to fix it.

Here is the code I am using in the terminal:

```
for file in /Users/path/to/folder/*
do
    curl -X POST --data-binary @$file \
    'http://croppola.com/croppola/image.jpg?aspectRatio=1.1&width=50%&algorithm=croppola' \
    > $file
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going wrong. The files were being uploaded and downloaded to the same folder at the same time which was canceling the process on the Croppolla servers. Updated code:

for file in /path/to/file/*
do
    FILE="$file"
    basename "$FILE"
    f="$(basename -- $FILE)"
    echo "$f"
    curl -X POST --data-binary @$file \
    'http://croppola.com/croppola/image.jpg?aspectRatio=1.1&width=50%&algorithm=croppola' \

> /path/to/file/Cropped/"$f"

done;

Comment: `for file in /path/to/file/* do FILE="$file" basename "$FILE" f="$(basename -- $FILE)" echo "$f" curl -X POST --data-binary @$file \ 'http://croppola.com/croppola/image.jpg?aspectRatio=1.1&width=50%&algorithm=croppola' \

/path/to/file/Cropped/"$f"

done;`